# Pandas: Extract date from unconventional timestamp -- YYY/MM/DD:HH:MM:SS AM

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have data in the following format:

```
d = {'Name': ['bob', 'george'], 'date1': ['2014/05/12:12:00:00 AM', '2014/05/15:12:00:00 AM'], 'date2': ['2014/08/31:11:59:59 PM', '2014/08/12:11:59:59 PM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   Name                   date1                   date2
0     bob  2014/05/12:12:00:00 AM  2014/08/31:11:59:59 PM
1  george  2014/05/15:12:00:00 AM  2014/08/12:11:59:59 PM
```

How do I manipute the two date columns to get the following format?

Expected output:

```
     Name       date1       date2
0     bob  2014-05-12  2014-08-31
1  george  2014-05-15  2014-08-12
```

Comment: Do you want the dates as timestamps or just strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format`:

```
In [1177]: df.date1 = pd.to_datetime(df.date1, format='%Y/%m/%d:%I:%M:%S %p').dt.date     
In [1178]: df.date2 = pd.to_datetime(df.date2, format='%Y/%m/%d:%I:%M:%S %p').dt.date  

In [1179]: df    
Out[1179]: 
     Name       date1       date2
0     bob  2014-05-12  2014-08-31
1  george  2014-05-15  2014-08-12
```

Comment: It'll work since you're only interested in the date part. The column however is in 12 hour format and not in 24 hour format.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.to_datetime` with the `format` argument:

```
df['date1'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date1'], format='%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M:%S %p')
```

Pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Formatting documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
dates = ['date1','date2']
df[dates] = df[dates].apply(lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x).dt.normalize())
```

Output:

```
     Name      date1      date2
0     bob 2014-05-12 2014-08-31
1  george 2014-05-15 2014-08-12
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d = {'Name': ['bob', 'george'], 'date1': ['2014/05/12:12:00:00 AM', '2014/05/15:12:00:00 AM'], 'date2': ['2014/08/31:11:59:59 PM', '2014/08/12:11:59:59 PM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], format='%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M:%S %p').dt.date
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'], format='%Y/%m/%d:%H:%M:%S %p').dt.date
print(df)

     Name       date1       date2
0     bob  2014-05-12  2014-08-31
1  george  2014-05-15  2014-08-12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

d = {'Name': ['bob', 'george'], 'date1': ['2014/05/12:12:00:00 AM', '2014/05/15:12:00:00 AM'], 'date2': ['2014/08/31:11:59:59 PM', '2014/08/12:11:59:59 AM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
date_extractor = lambda dts : datetime.strptime(dts, '%Y/%m/%d:%I:%M:%S %p').date()
df['date1'] = df['date1'].apply(date_extractor)
df['date2'] = df['date2'].apply(date_extractor)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Name       date1       date2
0     bob  2014-05-12  2014-08-31
1  george  2014-05-15  2014-08-12
```